# Recursive indexing failed at level 2 in R

Tags: r

When I run the code below, I encounter this error: Error in classes[[which(cramersV == max(cramersV))]] : recursive indexing failed at level 2. It seems that the problem rises when I use "which" inside of the list classes

```
new_var_cat=list()
new_var_cat[[1]]=new_var
V_Cramer_perclass=vector()
for(j in 2:91){

classes=list()
tbl=list()
cramersV=vector()

  for(i in 1:(101-j)){
  a_index=vector()
  for(k in 0:(j-1)){a_index=c(a_index,which(new_var_cat[[j-1]]==i+k))}
  temp=new_var_cat[[j-1]]
  temp[a_index]=i
  classes[[i]]=c(new_var_cat[[j-1]][-a_index],temp[a_index])
  }


  for(i in 1:(101-j)){
  tbl[[i]]=table(classes[[i]],pb_default)
    }

  for(i in 1:(101-j)){
  cramersV=c(cramersV,sqrt(unname(chisq.test(tbl[[i]])$statistic)/(n*(min(nrow(tbl[[i]])-1,ncol(tbl[[i]])-1)))))
    }

  new_var_cat[[j]]=classes[[which(cramersV==max(cramersV))]]
  V_Cramer_perclass=c(V_Cramer_perclass,max(cramersV))
}
```

Comment: I get `> new_var_cat[[1]]=new_var Error: object 'new_var' not found`. Please make the example reproducible.

Comment: What if you change `classes[[which(cramersV==max(cramersV))]]` to `classes[which(cramersV==max(cramersV))]`?